# cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::string *' to 'std::string'

Tags: c++, c++11

Not sure why this is happening, it seems like everything is lined up the way it should be unless there is something I am missing. I can't pass these variables and no matter what I try to throw at the compiler, it just gives me another error.

This is my code so far.

```
void parse(string name, string storage_1, string storage_2, string storage_3)
{//some code
}

//some more code

int start = 0;
int length = 0;
string param_1, param_2, param_3;



while (!infile.eof())
{
    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "ERROR: File " << file << " could not be located!" << endl << endl;
        break;
    }

    param_1.clear();
    param_2.clear();
    param_3.clear();
    line_input.clear();

    getline(infile, line_input);

    parse(line_input, &param_1, &param_2, &param_3);

    cout << param_1 << endl << param_2 << endl << param_3 << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're doing `&param_x` instead of simply `param_x`?

Comment: The compiler error says it: You are passing pointers to your parse function, but it expects strings.

Comment: I want to modify the param_x variables themselves

Comment: Then make the parameters of type std::string& and do not use an & when calling. In other words, call as follows: "parse(line_input, param_1, param_2, param_3)."

Comment: You should be checking the result of `getline` before using the string, not just checking for `eof` every so often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function declaration:

```
void parse(string name, string storage_1, string storage_2, string storage_3)
```

The second, third, and forth arguments are a `string` passed by value.

But in the function call:

```
string param_1, param_2, param_3;
parse(line_input, &param_1, &param_2, &param_3);
```

You are passing addresses to these strings (pointers).

You may change the declaration to:

```
void parse(string name, string* storage_1, string* storage_2, string* storage_3)
```

Or change the function call to use references:

```
void parse(string name, string& storage_1, string& storage_2, string& storage_3)
parse(line_input, param_1, param_2, param_3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explanatory.  You are passing pointers where pointers are not expected.  Specifically, you are using the `&` operator to pass your parameter values to `parse()`, but it does not want pointers.

Since `parse()` is intended to output the parsed values, you need to either:

1. change `parse()` to use references, and remove the `&` operator when calling `parse()`:

   ```
   void parse(string name, string &storage_1, string &storage_2, string &storage_3)
   {
       //some code
       storage_1 = ...;
       storage_2 = ...;
       storage_3 = ...;
   }

   parse(line_input, param_1, param_2, param_3);
   ```
2. change `parse()` to work with pointers instead, and keep the `&` operator:

   ```
   void parse(string name, string *storage_1, string *storage_2, string *storage_3)
   {
       //some code
       *storage_1 = ...;
       *storage_2 = ...;
       *storage_3 = ...;
   }

   parse(line_input, &param_1, &param_2, &param_3);
   ```

If all three parameters are required, use #1.  If any of the parameters can be optional use #2.

Answer (score 0):

In your call to parse, you are passing `&param_1`, which creates a `string*`, instead of plain `param_1`, which would be the `string` that your function expects.